# Design Issue with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, observer-pattern, qt5

using Qt 5.0.0

The following is roughly an `Observer` pattern (the code is stripped to bare minimum to explain only the problem):

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        void registerListner(Observer *pObs);
        static A* getInstance();
    signals:
        void sig();
};

void A::registerListner(Observer *pObs)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sig()), pObs, SLOT(slo));
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Observer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
        virtual void slo() = 0;
};

class ConcreteObserver : public Observer , public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public: //re-mentioning "slots" is not necessary
        virtual void slo();
};

ConcreteObserver *pCObs = new ConcreteObserver;
A::getInstance()->registerListner(pCObs);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

problem (apart from dreaded-diamond):
Can't inherit multiple times from QObject - moc does not allow it.
One possible solution is derive Observer from QWidget and then ConcreteObserver from Observer alone. However this is putting a constraint on ConcreteObserver. Maybe ConcreteObserver_2 needs to derive from QDialog instead etc.

How do i solve this design problem? Is there anything specific to Qt 5.0.0 Signal-Slot (in addition to earlier versions) that can solve this, or what would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you need that Observer class at all?

Comment: for observer pattern :) That was the selected design. May not seem apparent here but will make sense if one goes through the entire project requirement. This is just bare minimum to show where the problem is

Comment: In your example above you don't need it. You could pass `QObject*` to `A`'s `registerListener`.

Comment: @Mat but `QObject` does not contain the user defined slot `slo`. How would it work? Besides i want to put a constraint by design that all classes being registered should have reimplemented slot `slo`. Or maybe i'm not understanding you fully - explain yourself further in that case

Comment: Your code will compile fine if you change the parameter to `QObject*`, but you'll get warnings at runtime if that specific QObject doesn't implement the slot. (Program won't fail, it just won't connect anything.) You can do a runtime check if you want too.

Comment: @Mat : that's the whole point of software design - anyone not implementing `slo` and registering is useless and must not be allowed (except by way of hacks and cheating). That's the reason for this pattern in some way. There are hundreds of other functions and stuffs. You don't want the user of your library to `forget` to re-implement them. Nor would you want `casual users` to just register for no purpose.

Comment: You'll notice the whole signal/slot mechanism you're trying to use doesn't adhere to your standards regarding "the whole point of software design", it's mostly runtime checked. But that whole mechanism in Qt already allows you to do what you want natively without your observer class (with runtime checks again). `assert` in the register code with a nice message if the passed parameter doesn't meet the requirements, bugs will be hit real fast and you can print a nice link to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If runtime warnings are not enough for you, you can add a bit of compile-time type checking by making `registerListener` a function template and avoid multiple inheritance of `QObject` by not defining an `Observer` class per-se.

Here's what this could look like: (Note: my SFINAE skills are non-existent, this could probably be made nicer.)

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

#include <type_traits>

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void registerListener(T *pObs)
        {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<QObject, T>::value,
                          "Listener must be a QObject");
            static_assert(std::is_same<void, 
                                       decltype(std::declval<T>().slo())
                                      >::value,
                          "Slot slo must have signature void slo();");
            connect(this, SIGNAL(sig()), pObs, SLOT(slo()));
        }
        static A* getInstance() { return instance; }
        static void init() { instance = new A; }
        void doStuff() { emit sig(); }
    signals:
        void sig();
    private:
        static A *instance;
};
```

A few test cases:

```
class BadObject1 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        BadObject1() {}
    public slots:
        void slo(int){}
};
class BadObject2 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        BadObject2() {}
    public slots:
        int slo(){return 0;}
};
struct BadObject3 {
    void slo();
};

class ObservedObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        ObservedObject(QString const& name): QObject() {
            setObjectName(name);
        }
    public slots:
        virtual void slo(){
            qDebug() << objectName();
        }
};
class ObservedObject2 : public ObservedObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        ObservedObject2(QString const& name)
          : ObservedObject(name + " (derived)") {}
};
```

And a main file:

```
#include "A.h"

A* A::instance = 0;

int main(int , char **)
{
    A::init();
    A::getInstance()->registerListener(new BadObject1);
    A::getInstance()->registerListener(new BadObject2);
    A::getInstance()->registerListener(new BadObject3);
    A::getInstance()->registerListener(new ObservedObject("foo"));
    A::getInstance()->registerListener(new ObservedObject2("bar"));
    A::getInstance()->doStuff();
}
```

You'll get compiler errors for all the `BadObjectN` cases. If you comment them out, the output will look like:

```
"foo" 
"bar (derived)"
```

---

A warning though: this will *not* check if the `void slo();` member is indeed a slot. You can check that at runtime with something like:

```
if (pObs->metaObject()->indexOfSlot("slo()") == -1) {
    qDebug() << "Class" << pObs->metaObject()->className() 
                        << "doesn't have a slo slot.";
   ::exit(1);
}
```

This will work and do what is expected (unless you've got a class hierarchy where the slot wasn't declared virtual - then strange things will happen in derived classes that omit the `slots` "specifier". So I advocate that your docs not have the comment you have above about that specifier: it is always a good idea to have it when overloading a slot).

I don't believe this last check is achievable at compile-time, "slot resolution" is done with a runtime walk of the QObject meta-data and involves parsing moc-generated strings. Even if it was with some recursive template magic, I don't think it's work the effort. You'll get a runtime error message at registration type in which you can include the actual class name of the faulty object. That's a very accurate error message, and should be caught by the simplest testcases.

Comment: :) you have gone much into c++11. I cannot do that right away as i lack knowledge of newer features plus other developers in the team  might have issues too. It's not elegant as well. I'll stick to runtime assesrtion on return value of connect(...). If you edit this answer of yours to include that (from one of your comments above) then i'll mark it as accepted. thanks for the insight though. should be useful.

Comment: You have a runtime "assertion" in the last block of code above. You can remove all the template and static_assert stuff and just use a QObject* as a parameter and the only thing you won't have from the asserts is the check of whether the QObject passed has a `slo()` method or not.

Comment: BTW: you can probably do these compile-time checks with boost if you don't have C++11.